# Unexpected result when testing a file existence

Tags: bash, vim

Let us suppose we have an empty folder in which we create the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    inotifywait -r -e modify,move,create,delete $(dirname $0)
    if [ -f 'asdf.txt' ]; then
        echo "YES!"
    else
        echo "NO!"
    fi
    # Do something that takes some time...
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Basically, it waits for files in that directory to be modified/moved/created/deleted and then, if the file `asdf.txt` exists, it prints `YES!` to output.

Now let us create that `asdf.txt` file and run the Bash script. With the script running, if I edit `asdf.txt` with Vim and write changes to it, then I can see a `CREATE` event detected by `inotifywait`, but the only output I get is `NO!`. Why is that? That does not happen with other editors I have tried.

Notice that if I add a small delay between the `inotifywait` and the file testing, it works just fine:

```
[...]
    inotifywait ...
    sleep 0.01
    if [-f 'asdf.txt' ]; ...
[...]
```

Is there a way to test the file after it has just been edited with Vim without having to add an arbitrary delay in the script?

### Update

This is related to Vim's swap files. In fact, if you edit your `vimrc` and tell Vim to avoid creating swap files this will not happen.

However, this script is to be run by end-users and I cannot expect them to have any specific Vim configuration (nor ask them to avoid swap files or change the swap files default directory).

I suspect there should be a way to do it using the `--exclude` option in `inotifywait`, but I have not managed to success with it yet (tried with `--exclude ".*\.swp"`).

Comment: Did you write and save the change? do `:wq!`?

Comment: @Inian: why would I need to quit? But yes, I wrote the changes with `:w`, of course. :-)

Comment: I think you need to add the `-m` flag, which says  `Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely. The default behaviour is to exit after the first event occurs.`, so in all likelyhood, you wait stopped after first `CREATE` event.

Comment: @Inian: note I do need to exit when changes are detected (and execute some code, as showed in the script), so I don't think the `-m` option is a valid option, is it?

Comment: I bet this is caused by swapfiles or backupfiles. That event occurs first, then your test executes while the file doesn't exist yet, then it gets written by vim while `inotifywait` isn't running, so it doesn't notice.

Comment: So without it, you are ideally expecting just one event, `create` which has happened. I don't think any of the other options matter then

Comment: @L3viathan: yeah, I suspect the same thing too, but I have tried with `--exclude` in `inotifywatch` without success so far, so still looking for a solution. :-P

Comment: @Peque As a test, put `set nobackupfile noswapfile` in your `.vimrc`. If the problem goes away, at least you know it is caused by this. You could then tell vim to save backupfiles and swapfiles in a specific directory.

Comment: @Inian: they do matter for the actual application in which the script is being used. They are not put there by chance. ;-P

Comment: but agree more with @L3viathan's suggestion here. It could likely be the problem.

Comment: @L3viathan: yeah, avoiding creation of swap files fix the issue, still wondering why using the `--exclude` is not working... maybe I am using it wrong. :-/

Comment: @L3viathan: how come the `asdf.txt` file does not exist anyway? I mean, it is always there, no matters if the swap file is edited first, right?

Comment: @Peque No, the file does not exist until you write it once.  The swap file is created before the actual data file.

Comment: @Fred: yeah, but the file was written once first (see where I say "*Now let us create that asdf.txt file and run the Bash script.*"). That means the file is always there, we just edit it afterwards (i.e.: first we create it, then we run the script, and only then, we edit it and see the unexpected result).

Comment: @Peque   In your current case, it is probable `vim` is modifying the swap file first, which triggers your event, and your code executes before the actual file is written.  You definitely want to use the `-m` option, which instead of quitting will output events to its standard output as they happen.  You will need to read the output in a loop (one line = one event), parse that output, and decide if the file is of interest to you (e.g. this is where you would, for instance, ignore swap files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting `inotifywait` inside your loop, use the monitoring option and pipe the output to your loop, like this :

```
while IFS= read -r -u 5 EVENT
do
    (PARSE EVENT)
    if [ (I am interested in that file) ]; then
        echo "YES!"
    else
        echo "NO!"
    fi
    # Do something that takes some time...
    # Do not sleep
done 5< <(inotifywait -m ....)
```

The code above uses file descriptor 5 to protect standard input in case your "something" requires user input.

One advantage is that you will be receiving events that occur while your "something that takes some time" occurs.  You may want to execute that "something" in the background (with `&`) if you want to avoid delays in receiving events.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why couldn't I use the `--exclude` option in `inotifywait` instead? Shouldn't that be working as well?

Comment: Also, the main question was "why is the file testing failing?". In example: the file `asdf.txt` is always there, we just edit it. And even if swap files exist, `asdf.txt` is still there, right? Why is the file testing failing then?

Comment: I do not see an obvious bug in your code, and I cannot test on my end for now, so my first inclination would be to believe that you think the file is there, but it really is not (at least not where `inotifywait` is looking for it).  Try using just the `inotifywait -m` (without the loop) and allowing its output to go to standard out and see if your command actually sees the real data file being modified.  This might give you some clues as to what the problem may be.

Comment: yeah, I did that. I posted an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Vim actually does a lot of things when saving changes to a file:

```
./ CREATE 4913
./ DELETE 4913
./ MOVED_FROM asdf.txt
./ MOVED_TO asdf.txt~
./ CREATE asdf.txt
./ MODIFY asdf.txt
./ DELETE asdf.txt~
./ MODIFY .asdf.txt.swp
[...]
```

Some might actually be expected (like creating and editing swap and backups files). But some might be a bit counter-intuitive:

- It creates and destroys a test file `4913` first in an attempt to
  verify it can create a file in the directory in which you see the file
  and set the uid/gid.
- It actually *moves* the original file to the backup file (that's why the test might be failing) and then creates a new file to replace the original.

Creating the appropriate rules and being a bit more restrictive when selecting the events `inotifywait` will trigger with, we could use:

```
inotifywait --exclude ".*\.(swp|swx)|4913|.*~" -r -e modify,moved_to,create,delete $(dirname $0)
```

Note that we lost track of `moved_from` events, though.

This could be combined with [Fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42273568/3577054) to treat Vim edits as special cases (i.e.: when we first see a `4913` file being created).

Comment: Thanks for posting the results from your test.  Sometimes one is looking for a bug in one's code, but the actual bug is in one's assumptions about what is supposedly going on.  With this additional data, it is easy seing what happened, and everything makes sense again.